How can I determine load bearing possibility before hiring an engineer?
Attached are drawings for reference (basement, main floor, 2nd floor). I've done my best to add context with colors/shapes/text.
We'd like to take down the wall between current kitchen/dining room to expand the kitchen. Then, open up the current 6' doorway from current prints dining room to living room to about 10'. We believe there is a beam (unsure on metal or additional wood for reinforcement) running east to west from the main floor bathroom to the east wall (pink line).


We'd like some perspective on thoughts for the kitchen wall (in orange) coming down. Is it load bearing?

We'd like some perspective on opening up the current dining room to living room opening (purple) to larger (green). Can this be opened up?

Do you think additional support (dark green dots) would be needed to help carry the load on the second floor due to a larger opening?




The kitchen/dining wall is low probably for load bearing.  The yellow box wall is load bearing and you do want an engineer for any changes to it.

Yes, the yellow box wall is the basement structure/beam for reference. Not looking to change the basement.
Main floor -- just the orange box (remove kitchen/dining wall) and expand opening where purple box is to about the size of the green box.

Look at the trusses in your attic.
Trusses are supported at the end points. If the end points are above the wall in question, its load bearing.
